# Casting data to type of variables stored in object[]

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to emulate the way fortran reads data from text files in C#. In fortran you have something like

```
        READ(60,2005,ERR=9880,END=8000) A,B,C,D
  2005  FORMAT(I8,A20,2F10.3)
```

and A, B, C, D are automatically set to the correct type based on the format statement.

I have tried things along the lines of:

```
    private static void Example(string[] Data, ref object[] Variables)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
            Variables[i] = (typeof(Variables[i]))Data;
    }
```

but can't even get code that will compile.

At the moment I'm assigning to the variables by passing out all the data in an object array, like this

```
    private static object[] Example(string[] Data)
    {
        object[] output = new object[Data.Length - 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < Data.Length; i++)
        {
            int dummyInt;
            if (int.TryParse(Data[i], out dummyInt))
                output[i] = dummyInt;
            /// Try to parse other possible data types
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static void UseExample()
    {
        object[] values = Example(new string[] { "     356", "Some text           ", "   956.365", "564050.201" });
        int A = (int)values[0];
        string B = (string)values[1];
        double C = (double)values[2];
        double D = (double)values[3];
    }
```

This is simplified, but is in essence what I am doing: determining the type of the data, casting to that type and passing all fields out as an object and then casting again when I assign to the variables that hold the data.
Which requires knowing what variables will come out and also a lot of extra coding if there are lots of data fields.

I am looking for a way I can pass in all the variables that should be set and set them to the correct value value, but for that I need to be able to cast the data to the type of the appropriate variable.

Can this be done? If it is possible, how can it be done?